# Finding coordinates of each pixel using programming

Tags: matlab, opencv

What is the  way to find the coordinates of each pixel of the inner circle (or the outer one) in the following Image using programming(openCV or MATLAB)?
imtool gives this information but it is  mouse driven.

[image]

**Update**

I used imtool to detect these locations, by putting my mouse cursor on each point on the circle and manual noting this value. But how do I do it using programming as manually I cant do it for so many pints on the circle.

Comment: what have you tried? You could iterate trough all pixels, and check if it is is black or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Matlab, you can just do:

```
im = imread('im.png');      %# load image
[y,x] = find(all(im<5, 3)); %# find black pixels
position = [x,y];           %# display them
```

Comment: Can u explain (im==0,3)? why 3 ? is it because u are finding r,g,b values equal to 0?

Comment: @gpuguy: see the syntax of [all](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/all.html). It checks if all values for a pixel are zero along the third dimension (ie all color layers).

Comment: @gpuguy : as said by @Junuxx, `all(A==0,3)` checks that the values of all of the 3 colors (third dimension) are 0, which mean that the color is black.

Comment: `im<5` is a more flexible condition, `im==0` might miss a few pixels if `im.png` was stored lossy and/or the circles have been anti-aliased.

Comment: That's true indeed. I left `==0` because it works on that image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to use openCV to find an object with hue and saturation filtering. 
Perhaps you can use it with thresholding black?

http://myrobotlab.org/content/opencv-how-isolate-object-hue-saturation-and-value

There is also a method for detecting circles here:

http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs4411/wiki/index.php?title=OpenCV_Guide

Comment: I am not interested in detecting shapes. I just want to get the location of the pixels on the circles. I can use imtool, but it will be manual; i will have to put the mouse cursor on each point on the circle and note down the location x, y.

Answer (score -1):

you can implement this code...

```
a=rgb2gray(imread('image.tif'));
[x,y,z]=size(a);
count=0;
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if a(i,j)==0
            count=count+1;
            new_x(count)=j;
            new_y(count)=i;
        end
    end
end
```

You can get the coordinates values from `new_x` & `new_y`

Comment: this is a **terrible** solution! (1) you do not pre-allocate `new_x` and `new_y`. (2) you use nested loops. This is completely **not** the Matlab-ish way of doing this kind of task!